# Почему снижается FPS? (Android)

Tags: android, утечка-памяти

Есть приложение, где надо рисовать четырьмя линиями. Но при рисовании постепенно снижается FPS. Вот код:

```
switch (me.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                leadonepath.moveTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
                leadtwopath.moveTo(me.getX() + 5, me.getY());
                leadthreepath.moveTo(me.getX() + 10, me.getY());
                leadfourpath.moveTo(me.getX() + 15, me.getY());
                startX = me.getX();
                startY = me.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                   
                fX = (int)me.getRawX();
                fY = (int)me.getRawY();                 
                if(fX == prevFX || fY == prevFY)break;
                prevFX = fX;
                prevFY = fY;

                calculatPosition();
                if (mScratchStart){
                    leadonepath.lineTo(fX, fY);
                    leadtwopath.lineTo(fX + 5, fY);
                    leadthreepath.lineTo(fX + 10, fY);
                    leadfourpath.lineTo(fX + 15, fY);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (isScratch(startX, me.getX(), startY, me.getY()))
                    {
                        mScratchStart = true;
                        leadonepath.lineTo(fX, fY);
                        leadtwopath.lineTo(fX + 5, fY);
                        leadthreepath.lineTo(fX + 10, fY);
                        leadfourpath.lineTo(fX + 15, fY);
                        allowdrawleads = false;
                    }
                }
                } else {
...
                    }

                scores += scoreInc; 
                h.post(updateScores);
                if(!allowdrawleads)
                h.post(updateCanvas);                   
                break
                ;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mScratchStart = false;
                try {
                    ...
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {}
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за некорректоное написание вопроса, т.к. пишу с планшета.

Comment: возможно, внутри вызываемых методов, есть сложные расчеты.

Comment: Нет, сложных расчётов отсутствуют

Comment: к сожалению, мои телепатические способности не позволяют заглянуть внутрь этих методов. Может быть там просто идет вывод fps через форматирование строки.

Comment: Если будет нужно содержимое onDraw, то могу выложить сюда